# jQuery Dialog z-Index not working wen ad's served on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ripping my hair out on this one!

We are using an ad company that serves out their ads by embedding an iFrame within a div element.

All is working, but then I was asked to create a pop-up.

The pop-up also works, but the z-index is not correctly set.

Within the div element of the ad is a div that has the z-index property set to 9999 and the position set to absolute.

The code I am using to make the pop-up display is:

```
            $('#questions').modal({
            backdrop: 'static' }, 'show');
```

The HTML for the modal pop-up is as follows:

```
<!-- modal content -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:960px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Tenant Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="min-height:500px;">

                  Something Goes Here

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button onclick = "recordDoNotShow();" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Don’t show this message again</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Sometimes, this code works fine, then others the ad sits on top.

Comment: If you can, don't serve the ads directly on your page. Put them in a sandboxed iframe and control the z-index of that iframe so no matter what the ad brings it wont be able to come on top of your page elements.

Comment: can't you just increase the z-index of your modal?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. atmd, I have tried that, but I does not help in anyway. XGreen, could you please expand upon the sandboxing methodology please.

Comment: The code inserted into the html follows this type of structure. <div><div style='position:absolute;z-index:9999'><iframe>STUFF</iframe></div></div>